# A way to describe a group of trees of one species using only one word

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, terminology

While working on a short story, I stumbled upon a simple sentence as I attempted to succinctly and expressively convey that a protagonist was at the edge of a birch woodland. I'm not fond of the phrases *"birch woodland"* or *"birch forest"* and would prefer to express this using just one word if feasible.

I'm only aware of a few examples, such as *pinery* and more esoteric ones like *oakery*. I'm not even certain if these examples aren't idiosyncratic vocabulary. An [osier bed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osier_bed) ([an explanatory article](http://nurserygardeners.com/?p=1220)) still uses two words.

My initial idea was to append the *wood* suffix to the name of a specific tree to create the desired word, such as *birchwood* for a birch forest. I'm unsure, however, if this is appropriate, as it seems to allude more to timber and carpentry material rather than a picturesque and vivid description of a grove.

I'm seeking the help of native speakers who are well-versed in proper literary style to describe a grove consisting of one tree species using only one word.

Comment: I can think of no single English word (or way of rephrasing the name of a tree) that combines the two things.

Comment: @JasonBassford I foresaw this but decided to give it a shot. What is your opinion on "oakery" and "osier-bed"? Are these valid? Unfortunately I can't recall where I saw these words. Perhaps you are aware of some other similar examples like "pinery"?

Comment: Sorry. Short of referring to a dictionary, those don't *sound* necessarily wrong, but nor can I recall specifically hearing them before. And even if *oakery* were fine, I doubt you could swap *oak* for any number of other types of trees (such as *maplery*).

Comment: I'm with @JasonBassford on this. Never heard of a single word for what you're describing, just the complex noun. Even "pinery" and "oakery" sound like a factory of some kind, a la "cannery".

Comment: You can say ‘a stand of trees’ such as ‘a stand of birch’ - a ‘stand’ means a group of the same type of trees. But there is no single word as far as I know. And you cannot say ‘oakery’ etc. So you can say ‘he stopped near a stand of birch’. You do not need to say ‘trees’.

Comment: @Jelila  Looks pretty interesting even though these are still two words. I wasn't aware of this usage of the word. Thanks!

Comment: In the context of forestry management (particularly with replanted forests), a word would be *monoculture* to describe the lack of natural diversity.

Comment: *I do not really like a word combination “birch woodland” or a “birch forest”* This is irrational. This is the standard form and there is no reason for you to dislike it. There are a lot of other nouns for groups of trees: copse, plantation, wood, coppice, covert, chase, etc.

Comment: Since you mention "pinery", note that "pinetum" is somewhat similar in meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can't say this in one word.

While it is difficult to prove a negative, I believe there is no general one-word solution that works for *every* species of tree. For particular species, you might find  a particular single word solution.

**To be honest, I'm not sure why you would *want* to use one word rather than several**; your answer doesn't make that clear. Were I you, I'd be happy with *an oak thicket,* *an oak stand,* *an oak grove,* *an oak copse,* *an oak wood,* *an oak forest* etc. as they are no less expressive than any single word equivalent that you might hope exists!

In your comments you mention *pinery*. A quick dictionary search shows that *oakery* [does not exist](https://www.onelook.com/?w=oakery&ls=a) and neither does *birchery*; hence it is not a general solution. Also, *pinery* is not a particularly common word, and I doubt it could be used for a pine *forest,* for instance.

#### *-wood* as a suffix

As for your suggestion of using *-wood* as a suffix, that just doesn't work. It's unreliable.

Were you to consult a dictionary, you would see that it is **not** the case that in **every instance** a tree name concatenated with *wood* gives the name of **a group of trees**; more usually it is just a **type of wood**, in the **lumber** sense.

While Merriam-Webster has [*birchwood*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birchwood) as both a material a carpenter might use and *a birch wood* i.e. many living birch trees still stuck in the ground, the same is not true with *oak.* In this instance, according to Merriam-Webster, [*oakwood*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oakwood) is only the material and not the collective body of trees; similarly, [*cherrywood*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherrywood), and [*applewood*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/applewood) are materials only. [*Ashwood*](https://www.onelook.com/?w=ashwood&ls=a) and [*rowanwood*](https://www.onelook.com/?w=rowanwood&ls=a) do not appear to even exist as compound words. (Perhaps they are not practical for carpentry or arboreal monoculturing... I have no idea!)

I'm not sure to what extent the *-wood* suffix is generative and whether there is any rule as to when it creates *woods* as well as plain old *wood.* Perhaps some linguist has investigated this, and a knowledgeable answerer will let us know. (However, it is probably just entirely irregular.)

---

#### Edit

*The question was edited in a significant way after I answered, which makes the above answer less relevant.*

**Coppice** *can* refer to a single-species wood or grove when it is vegetatively propagated. (A *coppice* could even be a grove or a small circle of trees where each plant is a clone of *one* mother tree.) As a transitive verb, *coppice* refers to a traditional forestry/pruning technique which results in the formation of *coppices* in the nounal sense.

*Coppice* is clearly a cognate with *copse* and it *can* be used with exactly that meaning. However, when this more unusual and awkward spelling is used, it is typically with the more specific, necessarily single-species meaning.

In its limited sense, *coppice* does not, however, refer to *any* single species stand or wood of trees; the clonal means of reproduction is what makes it a *coppice.*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coppicing) gives the following definition:

> **coppice** *noun*
>
> Definition of coppice (Entry 1 of 2)
>
> 1 **copse**
>
> 2 **forest originating mainly from shoots or root suckers rather than
>   seed**
>
> *an oak coppice*
>
> ---
>
> **coppice** *verb*
>
> *coppiced; coppicing*
>
> Definition of coppice (Entry 2 of 2)
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> **to cut back so as to regrow in the form of a coppice**
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> **to form a coppice**
>
> **specifically, of a tree : to sprout freely from the base**

Answer (score 1):

You can say ‘a stand of trees’ such as ‘a stand of birch’ - a ‘stand’ means a group of the same type of trees. But there is no single word as far as I know. And you cannot say ‘oakery’ etc. So you can say ‘he stopped near a stand of birch’. You do not need to say ‘trees’.

Comment: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stand) has, less prescriptively: **stand**: a group of trees, especially ones of a similar size, age, or type